# Deterministic random number sequence

Tags: rendering, random

I have an array of lights that I need to sample from randomly, but deterministically so that all the lights are sampled. Currently I use random numbers to pick a light, and then put processed lights into another list, but I'm wondering if there is a way to use something like a hammersly or halton sequence to do this instead. A biased solution would be ok.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand this, the sequence:
1,2,3,4
could end up as:
3,2,4,1 or 1,3,2,4 or whatever?

[Fisher-Yates Shuffle, or the Knuth Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) came up on wikipedia. It says linear time, which is good.

```
import random

def shuffle(x):
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = random.randrange(i+1)
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Comment: +1 for a simple in-place shuffle.  This is the technique I have used when I needed to access all of the elements in a sequence exactly once, but in a randomized order.